# Yii framework where in clause

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to fetch result with `where in condition`

```
$email = 'test@gmail.com';                   // This works
$email = 'test@gmail.com,test1@gmail.com';   // This fails

$users = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('email'=>array($email)));
print_r($users);
```

Where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [addInCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) for such scenarios.

```
$emails = 'test@gmail.com,test1@gmail.com';
$emailsArray = explode(',', $emails);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition("email", $emailsArray);
$users = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: How can i store `'test@gmail.com','test1@gmail.com'` in `$email` so tat i can add much more email id dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to achieve. 
If you want to look up all users with matching addresses, you may use `explode` to convert comma separated list to array:

```
$emails = explode(',', $email);
$users = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('email'=>$emails));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way...

```
$email1="xyz@gmail.com";
$email2="abc@gmail.com";
$users = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('email'=>array($email1,$email2)));
print_r($users);
```

if you want to check multiple emails then use CDbcriteria..

[addInCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) this is the best way...

for ex..

```
$email = 'test@gmail.com,test1@gmail.com'; 
$emails = explode(',',$email);
$criteria->addInCondition('email',$emails);
$user=User::model()->findAll(array($criteria)));
print_r($users);
```

didn't try this code practically but hope it may work/help you...

Comment: I may have more that 10 emails in such case how this works without loop